# Why is my JS Animation behaving differently than my CSS Animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-animations

The JS Animation is using the built in JS Animate function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate

```
myRef.current.animate(
                    [
                        {transform: `translatey(32.5px)`, offset: 0}, 
                        {transform: `translatey(-2260px)`, offset: 0.9},
                        {transform: `translatey(-2260px)`, offset: 0.95}, 
                        {transform: `translatey(-2247.5px)`, offset: 1}
                    ], 
                    {
                        duration: 4000,
                        easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.33, 1, 0.68, 1)',
                        fill: 'forwards',
                        iterations: 1,
                    }
                )
```

vs

```
                    .test {
                        animation: 4s cubic-bezier(0.33, 1, 0.68, 1) forwards spin1;
                    }

                    @keyframes spin1 {
                        0% {
                            transform: translatey(32.5px);
                        }
                        90% {
                            transform: translatey(-2260px);
                        }
                        95% {
                            transform: translatey(-2260px);
                        }
                        100% {
                            transform: translatey(-2247.5px);
                        }
                    }
```

Expected same result from both but for some reason the JS one snaps onto the offsets, while the CSS one is smoother and doesn't snap.

Comment: We don't know what library you're using that gives you the `.animate()` method. Please edit your question to make it appropriate for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @AndyRay I am using the built in JS .animate function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate

Comment: Can you make the JS version into a runnable snippet so we can inspect it? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in CSS, the `animation-timing-function` affects each `KeyFrame` instead of the whole animation:

```css
.anim {
  height: 300px;
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  animation: 8s cubic-bezier(0, -1, 1, 0) forwards anim;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0%   { width:  50px }
  25%  { width: 150px }
  50%  { width: 250px }
  75%  { width: 350px }
  100% { width: 450px }
}
```

```html
Here you can see the <code>animation-timing-function</code> has been applied 4 times.
<div class="anim"></div>
```

The `easing` property you've set in your `KeyframeEffect` option object is the one that applies to the entire iteration duration of the keyframe effect. This doesn't apply on each `KeyFrame`, but on the whole animation:

```js
const el = document.querySelector(".anim");
el.animate(
  [
    { width:  "50px" },
    { width: "150px" },
    { width: "250px" },
    { width: "350px" },
    { width: "450px" },
  ],
  {
    duration: 8000,
    fill: "forwards",
    easing: "cubic-bezier(0, -1, 1, 0)",
  },
);
```

```css
.anim {
  height: 300px;
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid purple;
}
```

```html
Here you can see the <code>easing</code> timing function has been applied only once.
<div class="anim"></div>
```

To get the same effect as with CSS `animation-timing-function`, you need to set it to all your `KeyFrame` objects.

```js
const el = document.querySelector(".anim");
el.animate(
  [
    { width:  "50px", easing: "cubic-bezier(0, -1, 1, 0)" },
    { width: "150px", easing: "cubic-bezier(0, -1, 1, 0)" },
    { width: "250px", easing: "cubic-bezier(0, -1, 1, 0)" },
    { width: "350px", easing: "cubic-bezier(0, -1, 1, 0)" },
    { width: "450px", easing: "cubic-bezier(0, -1, 1, 0)" },
  ],
  {
    duration: 8000,
    fill: "forwards"
  },
);
```

```css
.anim {
  height: 300px;
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid purple;
}
```

```html
Here you can see the <code>easing</code> timing function has been applied 4 times.
<div class="anim"></div>
```

Or to avoid repeating many times the same values:

```js
const el = document.querySelector(".anim");
el.animate(
  {
    width: [ "50px", "150px", "250px", "350px" ],
    easing: [ "cubic-bezier(0, -1, 1, 0)" ],
  },
  {
    duration: 8000,
    fill: "forwards"
  },
);
```

```css
.anim {
  height: 300px;
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid purple;
}
```

```html
Here you can see the <code>easing</code> timing function has been applied 4 times.
<div class="anim"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know this is how CSS worked compared to JS' animate. Figured they'd behave the same. Regardless, thank you for the help and teaching me a few shortcuts.